# SQL Subquery and summarize data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4jbh.png

I need to know the:
Number of invoices per customer and how many customers in total

I calculated how many invoices per customer but I stucked here:

```
select * from
(
select CustomerID,count(distinct InvoiceID) as 'Total Invoices'
from exam
GROUP BY CustomerID
) a
```

I need to see this kind of output:

Row 1: Customers  2   Invoices 2

Row 2: Customers 24   Invoices 1

Thanks for your advise

Comment: Please include the sample data and expected output directly in your question, as _text_.

Comment: done. please take a look

Comment: Reposting the same question while ignoring the comments for the prior post is a sure way to get downvoted and closed. And your "this kind of output" does not appear to match the image of your sample data. People will struggle to help under these circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Now you've explained the output you want, which is number of customer with n number of invoices the query is something like this

```
SELECT count(1) "customers",invoices from
 (SELECT customerID, count(1) "invoices"
   from exam
   group by customerID) inv_count group by invoices;
```

Slight update, I didn't look at your jpg, the invoices aren't distinct because of product:

```
SELECT count(1) "customers",invoices from
 (SELECT customer, count(distinct invoiceID) "invoices"
   from test
   group by customer) inv_count group by invoices;
```